# Xcode annoying delete breakpoint sound

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to turn off the annoying sound that plays when I delete a breakpoint by dragging it off? I know, there are some OSX utilities, which enable turning off the sound of particular application, but I would like to skip that option (I'm already using soundflower and it causes problems with audio output from time to time).

Comment: Have you looked in `Preferences > Behaviors`?

Comment: I looked there and there are many options, but I cannot find any breakpoint behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mute all sound effects on your Mac under System Preferences ==> Sound ==> Sound Effects.